# Статистика игроков в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте!Делаю игру на WinFroms С# необходимо сделать вывод статистики игроков.Сама статистика представляет собой List с двумя полями (игрок и его время,за которое он прошел игру),записи сортируются по времени,нужно обеспечить вывод этого List'a.Подскажите как осуществить, через какой контрл?(Слева должны быть написаны ники игроков,справа их время)Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте DataGridView - в первом столбце будут ячейки с игроками, в ячейках второго столбца время, соответственно. А вообще интересно, почему игра на формах?)

Comment: Простенькая курсовая работа,учимся ещё,цель не столько написать игру,сколько изучить формы)

Comment: не все игры требуют крутую графику =) хотя в текущем стремлению свести все игры к "однокнопочным", даже тетрис надо писать на OpenGL с крутыми спец эффектами, которые потянет только топовая видюха, при этом фигурки должны сами падать в правильное место, чтобы не напрягать мозг игрока...